# Is it possible to add a MGLPointAnnotation with custom colour?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I don't see any reference to changing the color of a MGLPointAnnotation on the docs or even on the MAPBOX-GL source. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no built-in API to use a standard marker image with configurable color. Something like this would be your best bet:

https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/marker-image/

I've just opened a ticket around doing this in the core library:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2250

Comment: I'm already using marker image in some cases. Looking forward to having the color option in the core library.Thanks!